# SSH forward all X connections from DISPLAY

Tags: ssh, x11

Right now at work we have a login machine where our home area is located and all tools are run on the compute farm, to run in GUI mode I believe the job is submitted to the farm and the selected machine will run the command with the DISPLAY variable set to what was in our local environment. This seems to only work with vnc right now, is there anyway I can use SSH and use a valid DISPLAY setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you establish a SSH session with X protocol tunneling, you can query the value of the DISPLAY environment variable at the remote side.  For example:

```
client$ ssh -X server
server$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:17.0
```

This value is going to be different for each SSH session.

If I'm understanding your environment correctly, you'd need to pre-establish ssh sessions to all of the node in the compute farm.  Then, when the job runs on a particular compute farm node, it'd have to set the particular DISPLAY variable that goes back on the ssh session you pre-established.